# Запустить несколько процессов с одного задания cron

Tags: php, cron, crontab

Стоит задача запустить параллельно сотню-другую файлов php по cron. Выполнение одного скрипта долгое (долго отвечает api), просто в цикле не получится, т.к. от момента запуска первого до последнего пройдет очень много времени, что крайне нежелательно. Как решить эту задачу?

Comment: В цикле создать в cron сотню-другую заданий, каждое из которых запустит свою копию скрипта. И назначить их все на одно и то же время :) .

Comment: ставить в кроне соответствующее число заданий. т.к. у скриптов разное время выполнение, то соответственно каждому необходим свой интервал запуска. какие-то мелкие объединить запуск этих скриптов в отдельный файл, который и вешать на крон.

Comment: вы главное этой сотней другой параллельных запросов этот долгоотвечающий апи не положите вообще

Comment: да как и всегда: `for i in $(seq 1 100); do команда & done`

Answer (score 0):

Сделал по этой статье https://habr.com/ru/post/68175/ на curl_multi_:
скрипт инициализирует почти сразу (тест - 20 url'ов за 2 секунды) все обращения по адресам исходного массива.
Простейший код ниже, остальное по ссылке выше

```
<?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, «www.example.com»);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, «www.php.net»);

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();


//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);


$running=null;
//execute the handles
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
} while ($running > 0);


//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

?>

PS: Мне пока хватит на данном этапе.
Спасибо за ответы, тем не менее это не призыв не предлагать хорошие варианты :)

Comment: пожалуйста, изложите основное прямо в тексте ответа (нажав [edit]).

Comment: изменил ответ выше

Answer (score -2):

Между командами поставьте && 
 Например:
 
 
`cd /opt && touch file`

Comment: это про что вообще?